# AngularJs Search functionality is not working when more than one special characters

Tags: angularjs

I have implemented Angular Js search functionality in application. When I have enter more than one special characters for example '**!@**' it will display all the results.I think the exclamation character is the problem. How can I resolve this? In their demo site is also not working.[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter)

source can find from their site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See you are working somewhat wrong, because it allows you to have the multiple special characters search, but in your case you are using "!@" it means not include all those result having "@" in it.
So, if you choose to have "@*" it will show you to get all the result having these characters together.

Comment: can i remove this expression like checking?

Comment: in checking i cant say anything, whereas in your data you can replace all the exclamatory marks with their corresponding uni codes.