# Some special characters are not searchable in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am  creating a search bar which get projects from API and shows them all are works fine but when I search for `#` or any character followed by `#` in the search bar nothing returned not  "project not found" functionality also. It shows only current page.I am using `AngularJS 1.2`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398344/angularjs-search-functionality-is-not-working-when-more-than-one-special-charact

Comment: Can you provide your code and SQL Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason being you have to encode the special characters before sending it to the server. You can use `encodeURIComponent()` javascript method.

NOTE: encodeURIComponent() will not encode: ~!*()'

To encode the above characters as well, use a custom method.

```
customEncodeURIComponent = function (tURL) {
      return encodeURIComponent(tURL).replace(/[!'()]/g, escape); 
};
```

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20873310/2079271)

Comment: `escape` method does not encode `@*_+-./` and encodeURIComponent does not encode `~!*()'` . Which means the custom method will not encode `*_-.` You have to include that in the custom method `.replace(/[!'()]/g, escape).replace(/\*/g, "%2A")` This will encode `*`. Refer to this [list](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for other values.

Comment: I have encoded but Underscore and percentage characters are not working, may be back-end problem